# Cakephp website blank

Tags: cakephp

my website working properly as development server but this website in local server running as blank page as Cakephp website how to possible as config properly and how running properly in local server

i have also upload data but blank display http://www.florentserieye.com/

Comment: man you simply open the index.php in firefox?

Comment: i have already run and trace index.php but redurect in another blank page

Comment: Check the PHP version etc on the production server. See if they are the same as local server. Rule that out to start with.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind this can come from your .htaccess file,
check if your prod server as the rewrite mod active.

it appends a lot what was your config on the dev server and on the production server also, is your prod server shared (like public_html/www).
finally the first thing to test is to check if rewriting_rules are correct (contact the server host to get correct info about rewriting rules on their server).

also a good thing to be sure would be to upload a fresh version of cake of the server and check if the page is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have copied the code from production to local with out clearing the cache. Debug is also not on so the cache will remain, while errors are hidden.

Turn debug on and make sure any cache in `tmp/cache` is removed. [ClearCache](https://github.com/ceeram/clear_cache) plugin might help too

Answer (score 0):

you just make little change in apache setting, go through apache/conf/httpd.conf and make enable "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" by removing # and then go to the app/tmp folder and clear the data from cache's folder named as model, persistent and views. Surely it will work and you can run your project on local